# Firebase Functions for sendEmail Confirmation

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase function, modeled after `https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/email-confirmation`

I have the following Database Rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "iv": {
      "contactus": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my Firebase function is using the following database ref

```
exports.sendEmailConfirmation = functions.database.ref('/iv/contactus').onCreate(event => {
  const snapshot = event.data;
  const val = snapshot.val();
  console.log('value is:' + JSON.stringify(val));
```

This firebase function doesn't get triggered.

My database structure is as follows

```
iv
 contactus
    -KrsVfIJ4R6z6HAvguC9
        contactDate: 
        email:
        message:
        name: 
        phonenumber:
```

I have tried adding {uid} , {userid} etc to the database ref and the rule, but it still doesn't get triggered.

What am I doing wrong

Thanks, Rajesh

Comment: you try change onCreate to -> onWrite

Comment: ask see structure your database

Comment: onWrite didn't work

Comment: you try this functions.database.ref('/iv/contactus/{pushId}').onWrite(event = {})  ?    Ask see structure your database

Comment: added the database structure, the pushId didn't work either.

Comment: show log cloud functions of you

Comment: the pushId works. I wasn't providing the right database ref.

Answer (score 0):

changed from :

exports.sendEmailConfirmation = functions.database.ref('/iv/contactus').onCreate(event => {

---

to : 
exports.sendEmailConfirmation = functions.database.ref('/contactus/{pushId}').onWrite(event => {